# Why my item in Xcode6 Storyboard become invisible/translucent?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have some items in Xcode storyboard suddenly become invisible as shown in the picture. I don't know what happened and how to make it back to normal.

[image]

Not only `pickerView` in the picture meet such problem, but also `buttons` in other Controller View meet the same problem.

Any help or link is appreciate.

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/23msnq0.png     add a link to the picture

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you added the Picker View you were in a specific *size class*, and now you are not in that size class. You have made the Picker View a *conditional view* (conditional upon the view controller being in that size class at a given moment).

It's not invisible but *absent* from the view controller's view in the current size class, because it's a different size class. Xcode is merely doing what you asked it to do, i.e. include this view only when in the *other* size class.

Answer (score 0):

If appears with gray color it means that you are using "size classes" and you have selected a class in which that pickerview  is "uninstalled".

To install the view for your current size just go to interface builder and mark the option "installed"

[image]

For example, in the image attached, im just installing that view for Regular width and regular height == just for iPads in Portrait and Landscape